# Form labels not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im new to ruby on rails and actually i read a starter book! The thing is that there was an example how to make an new entra in the database with an form in the new.html.erb
So the example goes like this

```
<% @title = "neu" %>
 <h2>Neuen Favorit erstellen</h2>
<% form_for :bookmark, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f| %>
<p>
 <label for="bookmark_title">Titel</label>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
<label for="bookmark_url">URL</label>
<%= f.text_field :url %>
 </p>
<p>
 <label for="bookmark_comment">Kommentar</label>
<%= f.text_area :comment %>
</p>
 <p>
 <%= submit_tag "speichern" %>
 </p>
 <% end %>
<p><%= link_to "Zurück zur Liste", :action => "index" %></p>
```

Somehow only the title, `<h2>`, and the last `<p>` is displayed in the browser! Nothing of the form is displayed! Thanks for help! Greetings from Germany

Comment: Zippie beat me to it. Plus look into using the Rail's `f.label`. Makes the code much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using <%=, not <%, to start all lines except for where you're ending your form. An example:

```
<%= form_for @order_item do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
<%= f.select(:product_id, options_for_select(Product.all.collect {|p| ["#{p.color} - 
     #{p.size}", p.id ] })) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
<%= f.label :quantity %>
<%= f.number_field :quantity %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Add to Cart" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

`<% form_for`

to

`<%= form_for`

Also, as Ryan said, use `f.label` to make your code cleaner, like this:

`<%= f.label :url, "URL" %>`